# How to edit MongoDB configuration file to include replica set?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have a Linux Mint/Ubuntu machine with a `mongodb` installed from ubuntu package manager (APT-GET). I try to edit `/etc/mongod.conf` using

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

activate the `replySet` field so that it reads:

```
# Replication Options
# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
replSet=rs0

# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

succesfully restarted mongod instance with: `sudo service mongod restart`
But, whenever I run `rs.initiate()`, it resulted in error that suggests `mongod` can't find it's config file

```
{
  "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
  "me" : "Leony:27017",
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 
  1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
  "code" : 93
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in mismatch of host name being resolved by rs.initiate() call and the bindIp specified in the configuration. 
Have you tried supplying a json argument to the rs.initiate() call ? Like below ?

```
rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", members: [{_id: 0,host: "hostname:port"}]})
```

Also please see the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16157)  in Mongodb, where Mongo engineer says, it is not actually a bug, but works as designed. So one need to  have consistency in host name in net.bindIp as well as the host name in replica sets configuration.

Also, in a production setup, it is better to have DNS names or entries in /etc/hosts to easily manage cluster. It is not impossible to do without DNS names or resolvable host names, but it is easier this way.

Also see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82592) regarding configuration file option regarding bindIp

Comment: Link is incorrect. Which ticket are you referring to?

Comment: It works and rs.conf() printed configuration with a member in it. I'm not so sure what really is happening here. What do you mean with hostname problem ? is this a bug ? I usually use rs.initiate() without any parameter before